# Make seems to ignore my CFLAGS and LDFLAGS

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, fuse

I am having trouble cross-compiling fuse-exfat. 
GCC can not find my fuse library.
I am running the build on a x64-64 machine and compiling for ARM.

As you can see here, both the include files and the library is there:

```
root@2a13b22d5372:/opt/sysroot/usr/lib# ls -al | grep fuse
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      943 Jul  5 16:31 libfuse.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       16 Jul  5 16:31 libfuse.so -> libfuse.so.2.9.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       16 Jul  5 16:31 libfuse.so.2 -> libfuse.so.2.9.9
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   719756 Jul  5 16:31 libfuse.so.2.9.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       17 Jul  5 15:53 libfuse3.so -> libfuse3.so.3.6.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       17 Jul  5 15:48 libfuse3.so.3 -> libfuse3.so.3.6.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   698096 Jul  5 15:47 libfuse3.so.3.6.1

root@2a13b22d5372:/opt/sysroot/usr/include# ls -al | grep fuse
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Jul  5 16:31 fuse
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    246 Jul  5 16:31 fuse.h
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Jul  5 16:03 fuse3
```

Running Configure does not give any errors.

```
root@2a13b22d5372:/opt/fuse-exfat-1.3.0# ./configure --prefix=/opt/sysroot --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-strip... arm-linux-gnueabihf-strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc... arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc... gcc3
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc option to accept ISO C99... none needed
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib... arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar... arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar
checking the archiver (arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar) interface... ar
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... 64
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-pkg-config... no
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
configure: WARNING: using cross tools not prefixed with host triplet
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for UBLIO... no
checking for FUSE... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating libexfat/Makefile
config.status: creating fuse/Makefile
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating libexfat/config.h
config.status: libexfat/config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
```

Make fails with "cannot find lib" error.

```
root@2a13b22d5372:/opt/fuse-exfat-1.3.0# LDFLAGS="-L/opt/sysroot/usr/lib" CFLAGS="-I/opt/sysroot/usr/include" make
Making all in libexfat
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/fuse-exfat-1.3.0/libexfat'
make  all-am
make[2]: Entering directory '/opt/fuse-exfat-1.3.0/libexfat'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/opt/fuse-exfat-1.3.0/libexfat'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/fuse-exfat-1.3.0/libexfat'
Making all in fuse
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/fuse-exfat-1.3.0/fuse'
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/include/fuse -g -O2   -o mount.exfat-fuse mount_exfat_fuse-main.o ../libexfat/libexfat.a -lfuse -pthread
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lfuse
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:399: mount.exfat-fuse] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/fuse-exfat-1.3.0/fuse'
make: *** [Makefile:363: all-recursive] Error 1
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the info here there's no way we can say for sure.

However, it's likely that the makefile sets the `LDFLAGS` and `CFLAGS` variables.  Variables assigned in the makefile will take precedence over variables obtained from the environment so your variable assignments are ignored.

I recommend you try passing the variable assignments on the make command line, rather than through the environment:

```
$ make LDFLAGS="-L/opt/sysroot/usr/lib" CFLAGS="-I/opt/sysroot/usr/include"
```

(PS It's almost always a bad idea to build things and run make commands as root--in fact it's almost always a bad idea to do *anything* as root, except for things that require it)

Comment: Thanks! That worked. However, I got another error "cannot find /lib/libc.so.6 inside /". I assume I need another parameter to tell it that "/opt/sysroot" should be the considered temporary system root? But it should still be linked to "/lib/" because the libraries will be located there on the destination system.

Comment: Ah! I fixed it by adding CFLAGS="-I/opt/sysroot/usr/include --sysroot=/opt/sysroot"

Comment: It's a bit iffy, but `make -e` means that environment variables override what's specified in the `makefile` too.  Sometimes helpful; sometimes dangerous or counter-productive.

Comment: You shouldn't need both the `-I` and `--sysroot`.  The latter should add all the appropriate system header files to the compile line.  Ditto for the linker: using `--sysroot` alone should do all the right things.

Comment: @MadScientist Yeah, I realized that later :) Now I am only using CFLAGS="--sysroot=/opt/sysroot" and removed everything else. Seems to work fine.